# Programação Java para cartões

Tags: java

Olá,
Eu tenho um leitor de cartões magnéticos KDE KT-2280 e esse leitor é programável.
Só que eu não sei como programar cartões, porque nunca mexi em programação para cartões.

Existe alguma biblioteca de Java para programar cartões?

Podem-me ajudar, por favor?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Chama se Javacard

[Oracle Javacard](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard)

Segundo a wikipedia:

> Java Card é uma tecnologia que permite que pequenos aplicativos
>   (applets) baseados em plataforma Java sejam executados com segurança
>   em smart cards e dispositivos similares com limitações de
>   processamento e armazenamento, como o Java Ring.
>
> O Java Card é amplamente utilizado em cartões SIM (usados em celulares
>   GSM) e em cartões para caixas eletrônicos. O primeiro Java Card foi
>   apresentado em 1997 por várias empresas, incluindo uma divisão da
>   extinta Schlumberger Limited (divididas em Axalto e Gemplus, que
>   terminaram por se fundir).
>
> Os produtos Java Card são baseados nas especificações da Plataforma
>   Java Card desenvolvidas pela Sun Microsystems, e suas principais
>   características são portabilidade e segurança.

Link para o Artigo [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card)

Segue um Hello World! em Javacard criado pelo Igor Medeiros.

```
 /*
 * Package:  br.com.igormedeiros
 * Filename: HelloWorldJC.java
 * Class:    HelloWorldJC
 * Date:     [[8 de maio]] de [[2005]] 14:55:52
 */
 package br.com.igormedeiros;
 import javacard.framework.*;

 /**
 * Class HelloWorldJC
 */
 public class HelloWorldJC extends javacard.framework.Applet {

 // CLA Byte
 final static byte HELLO_CLA = (byte) 0xB0;

 // Verify PIN
 final static byte INS_HELLO = (byte) 0x20;

 public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
  (new HelloWorldJC()).register(
   bArray,
   (short) (bOffset + 1),
   bArray[bOffset]);
 }

 // processa o comando APDU
 public void process(APDU apdu) {
  byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
  if ((buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] == 0)
   && (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] == (byte) (0xA4)))
   return;

  // Validate the CLA byte
  if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != HELLO_CLA)
   ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);

  // Select the apropriate instruction (Byte INS)
  switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {
   case INS_HELLO :
    getHello(apdu);
    return;
   default :
    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
  }
 }
 /**
  * @param apdu
  * @author Igor Medeiros
  * Get user id attribute
  */
 private void getHello(APDU apdu) {
  // cadeia de bytes com a mensagem: "hello world Java Card"
  byte[] hello =   {
    'h',
    'e',
    'l',
    'l',
    'o',
    ' ',
    'w',
    'o',
    'r',
    'l',
    'd',
    ' ',
    'J',
    'a',
    'v',
    'a',
    ' ',
    'C',
    'a',
    'r',
    'd' };

  // informa ao JCRE que será enviado uma resposta
  short le = apdu.setOutgoing();
  short totalBytes = (short) hello.length;

  // informa ao JCRE o tamanho da mensagem em bytes
  apdu.setOutgoingLength(totalBytes);

  // envia a mensgem para o host
  apdu.sendBytesLong(hello, (short) 0, (short) hello.length);

  }
 }
```

Comment: ué.. respondi a pergunta do cara e recebo negativo? o que você que deu negativo esperava? rs